# Using sed to find and replace a range of numbers

Tags: regex, bash, sed, sh

first poster here.

Trying to use sed to find and replace a word. Code is as follows:

```
configFile=ConnectionConfig.xml
sed 's/30??\" authentication=\"someuniqueauthkey/'$1'\" authentication=\"someuniqueauthkey/' $configFile
```

And I'd run the file like this:

```
./choosePort.sh 3001
```

When I run this code, there are no errors given like bad regex format, it just doesn't replace anything and the contents of tempXml.xml are just the contents of ConnectionConfig, unchanged.

What I'd like to be able to do is recognise any number 3000 - 3099 in the 30?? part of the expression, which I thought was what the '?' did.

The input line I'm trying to change is:

```
<host id="0" address="someip" port="3001" authentication="someauthkey"
```

Thanks in advance.
(Ip and authkeys in file blanked out for security reasons).

Comment: Can you please strip your code down to the part directly related to sed? And could you please post some parts of your input file?

Comment: What is 30?? supposed to mean. What do you want to match with this? Why do you esacape `"` inside `'`?

Comment: 30?? was supposed to be 30 then any 2 characters after  it.

Comment: I escape " inside ' because " is part of the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `[0-9]` instead of `?` to match a single digit.

```
sed 's/30[0-9][0-9]\" authentication=\"someuniqueauthkey/'$1'\" authentication=\"someuniqueauthkey/' $configFile
```

Answer (score 2):

To match a number you can use `[0-9]\{2}` or `\d\{2}`

In your case `??` would also match `30` only.

You can find a nice overview of regular expressions [here](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm).

Comment: @Jarob22: jep, sorry, missed the backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

First, the matching expression must be `30..` not `30??`
Then, you seem to have forgotten the `-e` argument to sed.
Try with:

```
sed -e 's/30..\" authentication=\"someuniqueauthkey/'$1'\" authentication=\"someuniqueauthkey/' $configFile
```

Comment: The other answers don't have -e, why does yours need it?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/30[0-9][0-9]\(" authentication="someuniqueauthkey\)/'$1'\1/' $configFile
```